# Регулярка для ограничения ввода цифр с 0 до 9, только в этом диапазоне

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как ограничить с помощью регулярного выражения ввод с клавиатуры только цифр с 0 до 9.

```
 Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[0-9]{1}");
```

Фильтрует только цифры, но не их диапазон.

Comment: `^[0-9]+$`?————

Comment: К сожалению, проходят в match фильтр числа больше 10

Comment: Если вам только одну цифру нужно пропустить, то вместо `{1}`, поставьте конец строки `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Решена проблема

```
 Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<![0-9])[0-9](?![0-9])");
```